# Adding pseudo classes dynamically

Tags: jquery, pseudo-class

I use the JQuery append API to build up the following message which contains a hyperlink

```
var initialMsg =  jQuery('<div>').append(
                    jQuery('<span>').text('Network connection problem.  Please check your network connection. ')).append('<p>').append(
                    jQuery('<span>').text('Click ')).append(jQuery('<a>').attr('href', window.location.href).css({'cursor': 'pointer', 'color':'blue'}).text(' here')).append(jQuery('<span>').text(' to refresh page.'));
```

I don't like the way I am explicitly setting the color to blue.  Is it possible to use the pseudo classes

```
a:link 
a:hover
```

here?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use css to set the anchor style? Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PsXZP/)

```
a:link {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: Blue;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: Black;
    font-size: 18pt;
}
```